# Frustrating issue with dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

I have a need to select an item from a dropdownlist, and then as the item is selected, run a method in my controller class that makes changes in the database, then refresh the page to display the changes accordingly. My issue is that I need to assign HTML attributes to my dropdownlist in order for the JQuery that makes all of this possible to work. This is my DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TechnicianId", null, String.Empty, new { @id = item.CalloutId, @class = "techdropdown" })
```

The only way to assign HTML attributes to a dropdownlist is to have this overload, and yes I am aware of the null value where my SelectList should be, which is the whole problem. Unless there is a workaround for assigning HTML attributes to HTML.DropDownList, I need to populate a SelectList.

The trouble is, no matter how hard I try, I cannot seem to make the SelectList assign the values correctly that I need. The "error" is that, for example, if I have a list of 3 Callouts on my page, each with a dropdown to choose a technician, only the dropdownlist in the first Callout object in the list will work (i.e. the technician I choose has a value assigned) whereas the others don't seem to have an ID value assigned to each item in the dropdownlist.

I'm not sure if this is making sense, but here is the ViewBag with which I populate the dropdownlist:

```
ViewBag.TechnicianId = new SelectList(db.Technicians, "TechnicianId", "Name");
```

Without trying to assign HTML attributes, I can use the normal `@Html.DropDownList("TechnicianId", String.Empty)` which has all of the correct values for each option in the list, except JQuery won't work the way I want it to.

Comment: Your `id` parameter has a "@" in front of it.  Is this part of the problem?

Comment: nope not part of the problem. Can you assist?